# FFmpeg decode video to lossless frames hardware acceleration CUDA

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nvidia, h.265

I have 1 second H.265-encoded videos at 30 fps coming into a server for processing. The server needs to decode the videos into individual frames (lossless). These videos are coming in very quickly, so performance is of utmost importance. The server has a H.265 compatible Nvidia GPU, and I have built `ffmpeg` with support for CUDA. The following is the configuration output from `ffmpeg`:

```sh
ffmpeg version N-100479-gd67c6c7f6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-shared
                 --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls
                 --enable-gpl --disable-libaom --disable-libbluray --disable-libdav1d 
                 --disable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --disable-librav1e --enable-librubberband
                 --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora
                 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264
                 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig
                 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb
                 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex
                 --enable-libsoxr --disable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
                 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

I decode the videos into PNGs, and am using the following command:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -hwaccel_device 0 -c:v hevc_cuvid \
       -i 0.mp4 -vf hwdownload,format=nv12 -q:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -start_number 0 f%d.png
```

This command successfully leverages the hardware acceleration for the H.265 decode. But, the PNG encode is done by the CPU.

Does CUDA have support for encoding of lossless images? The format does not need to be PNG, but it does need to be lossless. CUDA has a [nvJPEG Library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html), but JPEG is a lossy format. Is there a similar image encoding library in CUDA for a lossless format (that is also integrated with `ffmpeg`)?

**Edit:** Some more context....

I am currently using PNGs because of their compression-ability. These images are 2560x1280 in size, btw. On one hand, it is this compression that costs the CPU cycles. On the other hand, I am also limited by the throughput of how fast (and how much aggregate data) can I upload these frames to the upstream consumer. So it's basically a tradeoff between:

1. We want to extract these frames as quickly as possible.
2. We want efficiency regarding the image size.

Comment: There are no video processing facilities of any kind in CUDA

Comment: What is consuming these PNGs?  Why not decode the videos only when you need them?  And, why PNG... why not a simple raw bitmap of some sort?  More information about what you're doing might help us give you better suggestions.  In any case, as far as I know there is no PNG codec for CUDA.  And, NVENC/NVDEC definitely have no such support.  If you actually do need realtime or faster PNGs and your server can't keep up, check to make sure this isn't a threading issue... you can always offload PNG encoding to an array of processes.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for your comment. I've added some more context to my use-case. The performance-related issues I'm experiencing are not threading issues. Instead, I believe it's due to the large image size, and ffmpeg PNG compression (which by default is configured to be at maximum compression settings for PNGs).

Comment: What is consuming these frames?  If you're concerned about compression, why can't the original H.265 video stream go straight there and be decoded where it is needed?

Comment: @Brad, the upstream consumer is a ML engine that needs immediate random access of individual frames.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand the full architecture.  By adding an extra PNG encode/decode step, you're effectively wasting CPU on each end, while also losing efficiency in bandwidth usage between your ingest hosts and the ML hosts. Your problem seems to come down to that it's taking too long to encode/decode PNG (which at the end of the day isn't necessary) and that you want to make this all very efficient (which, the original stream is as efficient as it can get). Why not decode the video where you need it, when you need it? You have a 1-second GOP length... this seems sufficiently small.

Comment: So far seems like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and we don't have the full picture to be able to make suggestions. What formats does the Machine Learning engine support?

Comment: H.265 uses JPEG data, so you can't use that format and be lossless.

Comment: Agree with comments - the ML engine will have to be GPU-accelerated for the required bandwidth, so it probably has HW acceleration for H.265 (NVDEC).